# Laravel causes PHP warning (exception not caught) xdebug enabled, otherwise all is fine

Tags: xdebug, php-7.1

With xdebug enabled I can reproduce an error:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
cd laravel
composer require proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Proengsoft\JsValidation\JsValidationServiceProvider" --tag=public
```

Error:

```
PHP Warning:  Uncaught League\Flysystem\Plugin\PluginNotFoundException: Plugin not found for method: read in /tmp/laravel/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Plugin/PluggableTrait.php:49
```

Stack trace:

But without xdebug enabled, everything runs fine.

I am wondering if this is happening only for me or also for others, before reporting it to xdebug.

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2


Package: php-xdebug
Version: 2.6.0+2.5.5-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

Composer.lock for reference

https://gist.github.com/amenk/9d63975cf4aabf86288b79fb95e8156c

I tracked it down to the following function in Flysystem:

```
public function invokePluginOnFilesystem($method, $arguments, $prefix)
{
    $filesystem = $this->getFilesystem($prefix);

    try {
        return $this->invokePlugin($method, $arguments, $filesystem);
    } catch (PluginNotFoundException $e) {
        // Let it pass, it's ok, don't panic.
    }

    $callback = [$filesystem, $method];

    return call_user_func_array($callback, $arguments);
}
```

The exception is thrown in invokePlugin() but caught afterwars (if xdebug is off). It Xdebug is on, that does not work anymore.

I have a 1G memory limit for PHP-CLI in place.

**Bug Reported**: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a question, but a bug report. I can easily reproduce all kinds of wonkyness due to exceptions. Please file a bug report at https://bugs.xdebug.org — preferably with a lot smaller test case

Comment: Any idea how to make the test case smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Some more info / quick fix:

I was using

xdebug.collect_params=4

with

xdebug.collect_params=1

the bug does not appear.

Also the bug only appears after updating to PHP 7.1.15 - and it does not appear for PHP 7.2

There is also a warning about huge scripts in the docs:

https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings

> The setting defaults to 0 because for very large scripts it may use
>   huge amounts of memory and therefore make it impossible for the huge
>   script to run. You can most safely turn this setting on, but you can
>   expect some problems in scripts with a lot of function calls and/or
>   huge data structures as parameters. Xdebug 2 will not have this
>   problem with increased memory usage, as it will never store this
>   information in memory. Instead it will only be written to disk. This
>   means that you need to have a look at the disk usage though.